# Laravel: php artisan make:auth doesn't create routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am following [this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) to create a basic user authentication in my application.

When I run `php artisan make:auth` it does create the views. 
However, the routes that were supposed to be set automatically don't work.

It added the following lines to my routes file:

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

However, when I click on "Login" or "Register" at the menu (which was created by the Artisan command) it is thrown a 404 error as if no routes were assigned to the requested URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using laravel 5.2 version then use following code in `routes.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Or you may have problem with direct `url` browsing.
If then use `php artisan serve` from command prompt

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work either. I just found out the issue and I will answer my own question. The problem was that I was not using the command "php artisan serve", instead I was just access the public folder directly in my browser

Comment: Yea you are right but if you are using laravel 5.2 my code might be better option for you.I used to visit directly but nothing happened so it might problem with routes.php.

Comment: run this command for which routes are present.      php artisan route:list

Comment: If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it.Both answer work fine so you should accept your own or my answer.@Leandro

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy  Oh, sorry. I didn't know I had to accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use my application by visiting the local url directly, in my case `/var/wwww/html/appfolder`

It is required to run the command `php artisan serve` (in the folder of the project) in order to access the full capabilities of the framework.

It is simply and dumb, but this is not clear in Laravel's documentation. 
They should stress it there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your web.php route file

```
Auth::routes();
```

It add all routes related to laravel authentication.In laravel 5.3 when executing`artisan make:auth`,it automatically added to the web.php file.